# jQuery, get ID of a textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I've got a form with a text field defined as follow:

```
<textarea style="height: 60px; width: 100%;" name="F3414" id="F3414" rows="6" cols="80" wrap="virtual" class="frmTxa fckEditor"></textarea>
```

I need, using jQuery, to get the textarea `id` (in that case, `F3414`).

I've tried:

```
$('textarea .fckEditor').attr('id'); 
$('.fckEditor').attr('id'); / ... with no luck.
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert($('textarea.fckEditor').attr('id'));
```

you have a space between `textarea .fckEditor` in your original question, does removing it make a difference

**Working Example : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/QYJCb/)**

Comment: $('textarea.fckEditor').attr('id'); / $('textarea.frmTxa').attr('id'); / $('textarea.frmTxa').attr('id'); / $('.frmTxa .fckEditor').attr('id'); / $('.frmTxa.fckEditor').attr('id'); all returned undefined :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot for the working example. Let say that my application is 'weird' and the way they load forms isn't ideal. Using the console in Firebug wasn't helpful ... Adding the jQuery code in my form worked like a charm ... $('textarea.fckEditor').attr('id')

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the textarea as an editor, it won't be rendered as a textarea once the plugin is applied. It might be an iframe with content editable set to on.

Inspect the page source using firebug and try to find out the HTML structure.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by HTML structure. The HTML provided is the HTML I'm seeing when using FireBug. In order to replace my textarea by the editor, I need to get its ID. I could hardcode it, but as I have different forms and fields, it will be easier to get the id based on its class.